# How to enable and disable wizard depending on the current active view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have two views in eclipse one is my **custom defined** view and other is **project explorer** view, I want my wizard to get enabled in **project explorer** view but it has to be disabled in my **custom view**

how can i achieve this, please help

thanks in advance

Comment: What sort of wizard (New, Import, Export, something else)?

Comment: I have my own wizard for that purpose

Comment: So how are you displaying this wizard?

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication, it is under the category of NEW

Comment: There is no way to restrict when wizards in the New menu are shown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63919833/how-to-disable-not-show-a-wizard-in-eclipse   How can I make enablement work when a String value equal to a key.