# How to disable/not show a wizard in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I have a wizard defined in org.eclipse.ui.newWizards

In org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent

I set commonWizard with wizardId defined in org.eclipse.ui.newWizards.

Then comes enablement under commonWizard.

My question is at this point : What should I enter under "enablement" to make this wizard not shown in eclipse ,based on a variable I get in a class.

In our project we have this kind of enablement via "or" then "adapt" IProject and "test" projectNature.

But I want to have it based on a String variable that I can access via a method call.

Comment: You would have to write a property tester to access that using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point and use `test` in the enablement expression.

Comment: thanks Greg. I did it as you said, by propertyTesters.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to disable / not show a wizard under eclipse : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119904/hi-is-it-possible-to-disable-not-show-a-wizard-under-eclipse